# How to handle images sent by a mobile device?

Tags: php, image, file-upload, mobile

A peer of mine is developing an iPhone application that will allow users to post images on my site via my API. I am building the part of the API that will accept and process the images.

The mobile developer is sending headers like such:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="photo_1"; filename="photo_1.jpg"
    Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

When looking for the images sent, is it the same method as with normal HTML forms? Should I look for $_FILES?

Or, using PHP, how would I find his image?

Comment: Check the contents of `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't appear it's being sent via a form, i.e., `<form enctype=multipart/form-data">` and `<input type="file">`, so the `$_FILES` array won't be populated.

You'll probably need to read:

```
$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA
```

or do:

```
$rawPost = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php):

> php://input allows you to read raw
>   data from the request body. In case of
>   POST requests, it preferrable to
>   $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA as it does not
>   depend on special php.ini directives.
>   Moreover, for those cases where
>   $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is not populated
>   by default, it is a potentially less
>   memory intensive alternative to
>   activating
>   always_populate_raw_post_data.
>   php://input is not available with
>   enctype="multipart/form-data".

For more info, check out:

http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httprawpostdata.php

Comment: urldecode? I remember that if the client sends a POST with content type application/octet-stream, then the POSTDATA are raw bytes, in that case an image, and you would store it as it is, no need to urldecode it...

Comment: I was actually asking. If you remember differently than me, maybe you're right... PS: +1

Answer (score 1):

I suppose iOS is sending the whole file as a single block of data in the **POSTDATA** section of the HTTP request. You can retrieve the whole POSTDATA (not parsed):

```
<?php
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
?>
```

`$_FILES` is meant for reading files sent with `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in a proper HTML form. iOS is probably sending a plain old POST containing just a bunch of bytes which represent the file.

Tell me if this solves!

Answer (score 1):

See these answers I gave to similar questions (processing uploads from `php://input`):

- [userland multipart/form-data handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5561078/userland-multipart-form-data-handler/5602514#5602514) and also
- [How to validate if uploaded file is an image? [file sent via HTML5's File API, received via php://input]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767749/how-to-validate-if-uploaded-file-is-an-image-file-sent-via-html5s-file-api-re/5767773#5767773)