# How to turn HTTP_POST_RAW_DATA into an image?

Tags: php, image, http-post

I am receiving images from an iOS device, and from what I've learned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890574/how-to-handle-images-sent-by-a-mobile-device), I need to look for the raw post data with either $HTTP_POST_RAW_DATA or file_get_contents("php://input");

I can do that, but now I need to know what to do with the raw data, once I have it? My framework typically handles images that I have uploaded to a temporary folder from a web form...but this case is different.

How do I "upload" this data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`createimagefromstring()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php).

Comment: when using this, the example on that page does a base64 decode on the string first....would I need to do that?

Comment: @johnnie Nope, that's only because the source string is base 64 encoded to begin with.